# How to set root password for aws ec2 with mysql preinstalled?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 instance with mysql preinstalled.
I need to now use mysql - therefore I need a root password, however when I try and run:

```
mysqladmin -u root password [aBc123DeF]
```

I get the following error:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Thanks to any responders. J

Comment: You're not specifying the *current* password via `--password` or `-p`. As you might imagine, changing the root password requires valid credentials, as it's a bit of a sensitive piece of functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I never set a password for mysql as it was pre installed with the EC2 instance

Comment: Who provided the AMI? You can reset the root password via instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Awkward.. I've just looked through my AWS details and found the root password... that's probably why there's no info on google regarding how to find your EC2 mysql password! thanks for your help ceejayoz!!!

Answer (score 5):

Amazon EC2 never sets a password for the "mysql" root user. So you can either
a) use "mysql -u root -p" and then press the "Enter" key when asked for password. Or,
b) use "sudo mysql"

On my EC2 instance, both methods are working.

Answer (score 2):

**Configuring newly installed MySQL Server**

To update the password of root user do the following:

- `mysqladmin -u root password [your_new_pwd]`

To create a database do the following:

- `mysqladmin -u root -p create [your_new_db]`

Then restart your server

- `service mysqld start`